# Change style for noSelectionOption option

Tags: css, primefaces

I'd like change style for noSelectionOption, to make it more obvious it is a placeholder.

My test page contains:

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu id="region" value="#{codeTableFirstEntryTest.region}" class="ddh-dropdown" converter="#{regionConverter}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No item selected" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{codeTableFirstEntryTest.getAllData()}"  var="region" itemLabel="#{region.description}" itemValue="#{region}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I was able to change the style in dropdown (in options, green)

[image: first item in dropdown in italics]

using

```
div.ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper>ul>li:first-child {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

but I found no way to change the style (italics in my case) when "No item selected" is selected in label (red part).

**jQuery solution**

I found jQuery workaround, but I'm looking for something smarter.

```xml
<script>
    function applyStyle() {
        $('.ui-selectonemenu>label').each(function() {
            if ($(this).html() == "No item selected") {
                $(this).addClass("my-empty");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("my-empty");
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<p:selectOneMenu id="region" value="#{codeTableFirstEntryTest.region}" class="my-dropdown" converter="#{regionConverter}" onchange="applyStyle()">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No item selected" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{codeTableFirstEntryTest.getAllData()}"  var="region" itemLabel="#{region.description}" itemValue="#{region}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        applyStyle();
    });
</script>
```

see `onchange="applyStyle()"`...

Code generated by PrimeFaces for selectOneMenu is

```
<div id="region" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all my-dropdown" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="region_items" style="min-width: 203px;">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input id="region_focus" name="region_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-activedescendant="region_0" aria-describedby="region_0" aria-disabled="false">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <select id="region_input" name="region_input" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" onchange="applyStyle()">
            <option value="">No item selected</option>
            <option value="1000000">EURO - Europe</option>
            <option value="1000001">ASPAC - Asia/Pacific</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label id="region_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all my-empty">No item selected</label>
    <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to apply style for that label (my-empty class came from my workaround)...

Comment: So there is no specific class on the 'no selection option' one? Is it always the first (or last) then use an nth-child css selector

Comment: It is more difficult, see update...

Comment: I don't see something 'difficult'....  care to explain what it is? (Other than the html for the PrimeFaces part of selection not being posted)

Comment: the thing I want to specify style for is label (id="region_label"), into which the value is somehow copied by PrimeFaces, there is no class as you can see... Even in select, there is no specification what was "selected"... That's what I call difficult, I'd simply use select in plain HTML, I see no reason not to, but that doesn't mean there isn't...

Comment: There is, I think your selector is wrong, try `ul > li:first-child { font-style: italic}` in the online PrimeFaces showcase. No, this is not what you should use,but there you can see it should work with the 'right' selector' (you miss the real PrimeFaces 'dropdown' part in your html posted above)

Comment: There are two aspects - 1.) I want to make "No item selected" different in dropdown options and my CSS works as you can see on screenshot (and I didn't share PrimeFaces' generated code for that as it is solved and working) 2.) when "No item selected" is really selected into label I want to apply style there too (but only for that special value)...

Comment: Then there is a class present that it is selected (still assuming it is the first). I all checked this in the showcase and it works...

Comment: Ahhhhh **THAT** label. No, there is no option for that. You need jquery (or change the PrimeFaces .js source of this component to add it there (if you e.g. want it for all identical components).

Comment: With 'no option' I mean not a really different one than you currently have. Some optimization could be achieved (e.g. reading the label from the selected option and not comparing fixed strings) but that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the `itemEscaped` attribute on `f:selectItem` works for adding styles to the `itemLabel` (for the `noSelectionOption`):

```
<f:selectItem itemValue=""
              itemLabel="&lt;span style='color:#ff00ff;'&gt;Select Your Option&lt;/span&gt;"
              noSelectionOption="true"
              itemEscaped="false"/>
```

You can add whatever style into the span tag within the `itemLabel` attribute.

I am using Primefaces version 8.0